# How to make a sprite move left and right when screen is tapped?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

so I have a game where my player needs to run left and right when told to. I have certain physics implemented so that it can jump when tapped, but it won't let me move forward or backwards on the ground. Think of a game like Super Mario where he can jump when told and also run forwards and back. Thanks(:

Comment: You should add your code to the question. That way we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `SKAction` to move or animate the player. The action you are looking for is `moveByX:y:duration:`. For example, if you have a sprite Node `player` you could say:

```
let moveAction = SKAction.moveByX(100, y:0, duration: 4)
player.runAction(moveAction)
```

the player sprite would then move by 100 points to right in 4 seconds. To be able to sense when the screen is tapped either use the `touches:` methods or implement a gesture recognizer. There are quite a few resources and questions on SO regarding these implementations.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but when i put the code in it keeps saying "use of unresolved identifier moveAction" is there supposed to be another constant or variable?

Comment: Also, could you specify a touches: method that I could use? Im a little lost.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to make it work by doing this:  let moveAction = SKAction.moveByX(100, y: 0, duration: 4)
        player.runAction(moveAction). I had to use let or else it wouldn't let me run the project,

Comment: yeah you need the let or var keyword. You should look into `touchesBegan:` method. Heres a useful link to get you started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=12158

Comment: "Swift 3"   let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y:0, duration: 4)
        player.run(moveAction)